Odoo 17 add translation button to tree view
I need to add the translation button (the one that shows at the end of a field when it has the 'translate=True' property)
I am working on a tree view with fields that are only readable.
I need to add that same button next the first field in that tree view.
I tried to use the TranslationDialgo from odoo's web module, but It didn't work well, or maybe I did something wrong
